# Android Studio Basic's First Excercise

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have been using Android Studio to create my first app. I am not using another IDE, Having gone thought the exercise I have reached errors in the following areas.

- My Activity
- Display Message Activity
- Gradle

DisplayMessageActivity

```
`package com.company.myfirstapp;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

import static android.os.Build.*;

/**
* Created by MyActivity on 17/10/2015.
*/

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}`

MyActivity

```
    package com.company.myfirstapp;

     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.EditText;

     import com.company.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity;
     import com.company.myfirstapp.R;

     public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      final public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "com.company.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Ap

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

final def extension = android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.myfirstapp"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}
final def extension1 = extension
extension1

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

My First App

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to                 `all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
    }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
  }
```

I have errors on Override and public void in Display Message Activity and Display Message in My Activity.

Comment: Please double check your code's formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix from (MyActivity.java):

```
   final public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Some message";  // fix this line
```

Your gradle script is all messed up, please change to this for the build.gradle of your app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 }
```

change to this then recompile, and errors should go away, also download any updates you need based on this script running. your on old versions of build tools, appcompat, etc.

And not sure what is going on with your first code snippet, it is not complete...